# Prove $a_{n}=\frac{- (\ln n)^2}{n + \ln n} \rightarrow 0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Prove $$a_{n}=\frac{- (\ln n)^2}{n + \ln n} \rightarrow 0$$

So I know the fact that $\lim_{n \rightarrow+\infty}\frac{log_{a}n}{n^{\epsilon}}=0$ (($\epsilon>1$, $a>0, a\neq0$)). Is it useful?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One may write, as $n \to \infty$,
$$
a_{n}=\frac{- (\ln n)^2}{n + \ln n} =-\frac{(\ln n)^2}{n} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\ln n}n}  \to -\:0 \cdot \frac{1}{1 + 0}=\color{red}{0},
$$ using
$$
\lim_{x \rightarrow+\infty}\frac{\log_{a}n}{n^{\epsilon}}=0,\qquad \varepsilon>0, \, a>1.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed useful, if you rewrite the expression for $a_n$ as follows:

$$
   a_n = -\frac{\left(\ln n\right)^2}{n+ \ln n} = - \frac{ \left(\frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}}\right)^2}{1 + \frac{\ln n}{n}} 
$$
Given your prior knowledge about the limit, for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$, such that for all $n>N$,

$$\epsilon > \frac{\ln n}{\sqrt{n}} > \frac{\ln n}{n} > 0$$

And hence for all such $n>N$, 
$$
    0< -a_n < \frac{\epsilon^2}{1+\epsilon} < \epsilon^2
$$
Can you finish this now?